# Intuitive explanation of tangent space of an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

My differential geometry professor said that the tangent space of an open set $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ at a point $P$ coincides with $\mathbb{R^n}$ , that is

$T_P(\Omega)=\mathbb{R^n}$

He gave an intuitive example for n=2:  if $\Omega$ is any region in $\mathbb{R^2}$, let'say a disc centerend in the origin, and $P$ any point in the disc, the tangent space if the set of all tangent vectors to  the curves whose traietories pass by $P$ and are contained in the plane. cleary the $T_P(\Omega)$ consides with the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ itself.

I tried to do my own example for $\mathbb{R^3}$,  according to that is not true that $T_P(\Omega)=\mathbb{R^3}$. If $\Omega$ is half a spheric surface,  and $P$ any point on the surface, It is absurd to say that the tangent plane to the sphere is $\mathbb{R^3}$, since is it a PLANE! as it is obvious form the picture,
so $T_P(\Omega)=\mathbb{R^2}$

What I am getting wrong? Please refrain from talking about manifolds , varities or technical stuff. These are not part of my course

[image]

Comment: A disc in $\Bbb R^2$ is 2D, whereas a spherical hemisphere in $\Bbb R^3$ is not 3D. If you pick an open ball in $\Bbb R^3$, then all of the tangent spaces may be identified with $\Bbb R^3$, just as with an open disc in $\Bbb R^2$. Similarly, if you let $\Omega$ be a semicircle in $\Bbb R^2$, the tangent spaces will just be 1D lines.

Comment: @runway44 Ok , but then the tangent spaces may be identified with $\mathbb{R^2}$ as intuition suggests, then how come the definition or  property is that $T_{P}\Omega=\mathbb{R^n}$, for $\Omega$ an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ then its tangent spaces may be identified with $\Bbb R^n$. Note that for $\Omega$ to be an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, it must have the same dimension $n$. In general, the tangent spaces of any manifold have the same dimension as the manifold itself.

Comment: @runway44 I don't see how taking an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ , the tangent space to a point which I think like the plane tangent to the sphere could possibly be $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I said ball, not sphere. Do you know the difference? What if someone, say the 2D version of you yourself, told you they don't understand how the tangent space to a point in the unit disk is all of $\Bbb R^2$ and not a tangent line to the circle?

Comment: @runway44 The ball is like a marble , the whole thing including the inside, the sphere is just the shell

Comment: Yes, for instance consider the origin. The tangent vectors at the origin in the unit ball can point in any direction at any length, so the tangent space is all of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: The term tangent is misleading. Think of it as (limiting) directions that you can 'move' in the set. This really is a case of math terminology gone bad.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know how a solid 3D thing can have a tangent in its interior, if a tangent is something that should touch in one point, that is why when I thing of  the tangent space to a ball , all I can think about is the tangent plane for a point in the surface. And a plane is R^2, not R^3

Comment: You might as well ask the same question about a disc in $\Bbb R^2$. If your surface is flat and you *literally* draw a "tangent vector" to a point on it, you've drawn the arrow on the surface itself, so in a sense it does not merely touch the surface in a single point but in an entire line segment's worth of points. That's why copper.hat said the tangent idea is misleading, and should be instead thought of as a description of which directions one can move in from a given point.

Comment: @runway44 oh, I think that is because I see it as the limit of a curved surface that is flattening. So tangent does not mean touching in one point, then. ok but for a disct in R^2 drawn on of piece of paper I can place another sheet of paper of the top  anchored at any point of the disc and I have that the tangent space is R^2. For R^3 I am trying to to the same, but for some reason I still think I have to do it with a flat piece of paper  like in the picture, since to do it with an R^3 object I don't know what geometrical object to take in the first place

Comment: You take another "sheet" of $\Bbb R^3$ and anchor it on "top" of any point of the ball. Of course, when you do it with literal paper on a unit disc you're doing it as a 3D being in a 3D world (at least, experientially). So to put a sheet of $\Bbb R^3$ on a point in a 3D ball you'd have to be a 4D being and do it in a 4D world.

Comment: I'm not sure if this point was made explicit enough: the sphere is *not* an *open* subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Thorgott, I 've been reading about it, but I am still confused by the fact that you use all 3 coordinates to represent a sphere.On the other hand it is true that you can only move in two directions while walking on the sphere

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use all 3 coordinates to represent a sphere". Of course, literally, it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it can always be parametrized by 2 coordinates locally (that's essentially the point behind it being a 2-dimensional manifold). Anyhow, the reason it isn't an open subset is simply because it doesn't contain any balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @mathlover that is no different to a 2d plane in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Keep in mind that to some degree, the point is to extend results from nice spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$ to surfaces. Keep the original in mind.

Comment: @copper.hat Why when we consider a sphere is ok to say that the tangent space at a point is a plane like in my picture, while when we consider an open ball the tangent space is not the plane anymore, but R^3? In both cases I can considerer  a point in the surface and the tangent space seems to be the plane anyway

Comment: @mathlover Think of a plane and one of the open 'sides'. In the plane you area restricted to two dimensions, in the open side you are free to move about. Try to map the question back to simpler spaces.

Comment: @runway44, In your example " for instance consider the origin. The tangent vectors at the origin in the unit ball can point in any direction at any length, so the tangent space is all of $R^3$"  do you have a way to picture  that the tangent vectors point in any direction or do you just rely on the extending the result in 2 dimensions where the graphical picture is clear? that is, that the tangent vectors are all the vectors contained in the tangent space, coincident whit $R^2$ itself

Comment: Simple: your $\Omega$, half a spherical surface, is *not* open in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Sure! Just pick any direction from the origin, and you can make a small straight-line trajectory within the unit ball with that tangent vector at the origin! (The magnitude of the tangent vector will just be how fast you go through the origin.) Therefore, the tangent space at the origin in the unit ball is all of $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You have embedded a two dimensional object into a three dimensional space however when you move to a higher dimensional space open sets in the lower dimensional space may not be open anymore. A simple example would be the interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which is open as it contains all of its interior points, however a line segment is never open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because it has no interior points.

In your example the open sets would be on the surface of the sphere which are not open in the ambient space. This is for the same reason, every neighborhood around every point will contain points not on the sphere and so it has no interior points, and is therefore not open. As you've correctly deduced this detail is non-trivial otherwise your get a mismatch in dimension.

Comment: How can I understand intuitively that the tangent space of an open set $\Omega$ of $R^3 $ is $R^3$ and not $R^2$?. Taking an open ball as $\Omega$, I can't help thinking that the tangent space is for a point in the surface still a plane, and  for a point inside I can't think of a tangent space.

Comment: My professor has defined the tangent space of a surface at a point as the set of all tangent vectors to the curves contained in the surface at the given point so that for a subset of $R^2$ the tangent space coincides with $R^2$ itself, but I fail to do the same for a subset of $R^3$

Comment: @mathlover you're trying to visualize a four dimensional embedding of a three dimensional space. This can prove problematic. Consider the tangent space as an approximation of the underlying open set. If the open set is on the surface of the sphere, the approximation should resemble the open set being approximated. Bump it down a dimension. In this case you'd find a tangent line associated with a point defined on some small open neighborhood.  The line is one dimensional because the graph is one dimensional, not the plane it's drawn in.

Comment: If the  tangent space is an approximation of the underlying open set, I don't see how all of $R^3$ can be an approximation of an open ball, For one thing $R^3$ is infinite while, the sphere is not, so they don't resemble each other. Furthermore, I am not sure in what sense are you talking about an approximation.

Comment: Somegave an example above " for instance consider the origin. The tangent vectors at the origin in the unit ball can point in any direction at any length, so the tangent space is all of R3" , but I fail to understand it. According to this  I picture a vector  in the open ball as a needle inserted into a basketball, How can that be a tangent if it going through the ball and not tangent to it?

Comment: @mathlover An open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a full ball, not the surface. The boundary of an interval is just two points and clearly has different topological properties than the interval itself. This is the same for the two dimensional boundary of a three dimensional ball. Notice how the tangent line only approximates the graph on a tiny region but we extend it to the full line. Expanding the linear approximation, ie the tangent space, to full size and it becomes the full space just like the tangent line becomes all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mathlover also, the sphere is certainly infinite but it's compact. You can actually compactify any space by adding a single point. It's called the one-point compactification. It's equivalent to stereographic projection of the plane onto the surface of a sphere.

Comment: @mathlover you're confusing surfaces as 3-dimensional objects. You should first and foremost try to understand that a surface, which is just a synonym for 2-dimensional submanifolds of the $\mathbb{R}^n$ is NOT a 3-dimensional object just because it's a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: A basketball mathematically models a sphere, not a ball. You might as well pick a hula hoop to illustrate why the tangent space at the origin of a disc shouldn't be the plane! A hula hoop is not a disc, a frisbee is! As for approximations, only small tangent vectors are approximations - go back to calc I in which we can approximate $f(x)$ near $x=a$ by the linear function $f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$; this approximation gets worse the further $x$ is from $a$.